# how to use "closure-compiler " inside the java

Tags: java, google-closure-compiler, rhino

I'm using closure-compiler which is provided by Google. I have JavaScript's in the string variable. need to compress the string using closure-compiler in java

I already tried the code from the following link  http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html

This is the code I used "source" variable has the value of the javascript

```
Compiler compiler = new Compiler();

CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();
// Advanced mode is used here, but additional options could be set, too.

CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options);

compiler.compile(source, options);

return compiler.toSource();
```

I have error in the following line: `compiler.compile(source, options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler.complier() method does not require 2 parameters but it requires 3 parameters.

Have a look at this [link](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/test/com/google/debugging/sourcemap/SourceMapTestCase.java). 
You will understand the number and kind of parameters required for the method you are calling.

Comment: If this answer solves your purpose then you can accept it as your answer.

Comment: hi VJ i got the following code from the link:
`compiler.compile(EXTERNS, inputs, options);` 
 what is the  meaning of  `EXTERNS` and what it used for?

Comment: EXTERNS is a ImmutableList of SourceFile class and even I am not aware of that why to use this because I am also new to this.

Comment: `externs` are only used during advanced compilation and it tells the compiler the names of the symbols that should not be renamed during the compilation, see https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/externs-and-exports